# Compile on save function not working, not showing any errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

Currently working on a web project in visual studio 2015 in typeScript.
Yesterday I updated VS to update 3 and updated my typscript extension to 2.1.

Now visual studio is acting very weird when I try to use the compile on save function.
When I run the project it compiles and open as usual but when I save the status bar reports "Project contained errors. Output generation skipped."
The source map (js.map) files are updated correctly but the combined .js file is not (very confusing). 
I don't have anything in the error list and compiling works fine if I do it with a "tsc --watch" in the cmd.

How should I go about to find out what is wrong in the project? Can I force the compilation somehow, since there doesn't seem to be anything actually wrong with the code?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly no, had to keep working so started using node -tsc with that compile on save. It's slower though.

Comment: Having the same issue with 2.3 after applying all the latest 2015 updates.